# Screen resolution black screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, resolution

I have changed my windows 7 screen resolution. Now it had gone blank. I tried it many times but it did not start. But in safe mode it runs.

Comment: More information please. DIsplay, GPU, GPU Driver installed and Version?

Comment: Have you attempted System Restore back to before you made the changes?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to upgrade your video card driver.
You can check which card is currently use if you press Windows button+r on your keyboard and if you type the dxdiag to run and hit anter button, you should can see your video card model name in display section.
Or you can use everest fot sure detecting, but this is a litle complicated way for this, so first trying to download a fresh driver.